# wpf updating text block

Tags: c#, wpf, text, wpf-controls, binding

I am trying to create some form of updating area in wpf. It needs to be up datable as it will be connected to a live stream of text that will constantly need to be displayed.

The idea is that I will have a stream of data which will comprise of a UserName and Text, this will come in a random times and need to be displayed:

User:Test :: Test:TextData

User:NextTest :: Test:TestData

and so on each item on a new line, so the object needs to be up datable in a scrolling format so the new item will be added to the bottom.

Currently I am using:

```xml
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="LogDetails"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

However this does not really show the data very well, the data is just string based, does anyone know of a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: You want the texbox show a string that continuosly change ? Did you try to databind ?

Comment: I did not get the question correctly. Can you please elaborate how you would want the display to look like?

Comment: I have updated the question I hope that elaborates on what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little bit vague, but here a try:
As an option, why not using [TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx) instead of TextBox, if the text changes automatically?
Caveat: If you want to use the TextBox, don't forget to set the UndoLimit to 0 . Otherwise, you will have a lot of memory consumption, if you change the TextBox contents continously.

```xml
<TextBox UndoLimit="0" .../>
```

If your text is a concattenation of multiple string-elements, create a layout with a grid and use multiple TextBlocks to shown the data more nicely? Maybe there is also some data you can visualize as symbols?

If it is a log, maybe you want to fill a list with strings and set this list as the ItemsSource of an ItemsControl? Through the ItemTemplate-property you can then specify the layout of each item? Use an `ObservableCollection<string>`, then you only have to add the strings to the collection and the ItemsControl will refresh automatically. You can use ItemsControl, ListBox, ListView for such a log.